# Is there any English translation available for Tattvartha Deepa Nibandha?

Tags: vedanta, translation-request, resource

I am looking for this text for a while now. I have searched the internet thoroughly but I could not find it. Does anybody know where can I find the work mentioned in the title, in English, as an e book?

Comment: You can view it or copy and paste the contents of Tattvartha Deepa Nibandha at the following link. @Markec

https://archive.org/stream/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp_djvu.txt

Comment: You can add that as an answer. I can see that you've deleted after posting. Why? @srimannarayanakv

Comment: As I am not providing any answer,  duly quoting references,  I thought a comment is sufficient.  Shall I undelete it? @Rick Ross.

Comment: For this Q that is the answer. Yes,  you should undelete it. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: There is no full translation of it on Internet Archive. Just Introduction and Notes.

Comment: @Markec: I think you have not checked the pdf format link. (https://ia600306.us.archive.org/11/items/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp.pdf).  Check there.

Comment: @Markec Its better if you can add a bit more details about the book, like what it is about, who has written it (if you know that is)... then the readers will understand the book's relation with Hinduism ..

Comment: The book is about philsophical aspects of Pushtimarg, that is about Shuddhadvaita and Brahmvaad. The author is Vallabha, a vaishnava acharya who founded The Path of Grace.

Comment: Okay, you can add those details to the question's body @Markec

Answer (score 3):

You can find **Tattvartha Deepa Nibandha** on **Archive**:

- [Book format](https://archive.org/details/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp)
- [PDF format](https://ia600306.us.archive.org/11/items/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp.pdf)
- [Text format](https://archive.org/stream/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp/tattvarthadeepan015822mbp_djvu.txt)